# Convertir a Decimal en vbScript

Tags: vbscript

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
Porcentaje = 0
valor1  = 255
valor2 = 7336

Porcentaje = valor1 * 100 / valor 2
```

El resultado es 3.47600872410033 como estoy sacando el porcentaje quiero saber si existe manera de convertir este resultado en decimal para obtener 3.47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por empezar, no está de más indicarte que podrías usar un redondeo normal a cierta cantidad de decimales con `Round(numero, decimales)` sin embargo por lo que indicas en tu ejemplo, pareciera que estás buscando un truncado más que un redondeo. Para esto podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
Option Explicit

Dim Porcentaje
Dim valor1
Dim valor2
Dim Decimales

Porcentaje = 0
valor1 = 255
valor2 = 7336
Decimales = 2

' Truncado del valor a cierta cantidad de decimales
Porcentaje = int((valor1 * 100 / valor2) * (10^Decimales)) / (10^Decimales)
WScript.Echo "Truncado a dos decimales:", Porcentaje
```

Multiplicamos el valor por 10 elevado a la cantidad deseada y lo convertimos a un entero, con eso logramos el truncado, luego volvemos a dividir por el valor anterior para obtener un número con la cantidad de decimales esperada.

Answer (score 1):

Así puedes redondear:

```
Round(Porcentaje, 2)
```

Esta es otra opción:

```
FormatNumber(Porcentaje, 2)
```